# How to solve number and letter grid pattern

Tags: pattern

I'm having trouble solving a question in which there is a 6x6 grid pattern. One of the rows have been erased and I need to find what number or letter is in the grid square with the question mark.

- 2 A 4 A 6 A
- C B 4 B 6 B
- 4 4 4 C 6 C
- ```
    ?
  ```
- 6 6 6 6 6 E
- K J I H G F

The answer is supposed to be e, yet I cannot find why that would be the answer. Please help.

[image: The grid]

Comment: Where did you find this puzzle? Puzzles without proper attribution can sometimes be deleted

Comment: @hexomino It was in a numerical reasoning selective school practice test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reasoning

> If we highlight bands as in the following diagram a pattern becomes more clear
>  [image]
>  Notice that in the yellow highlighted bands we have the first few even numbers, beginning with 2 in the top-left corner, then all 4s, then all 6s.
>  In between, for the non-highlighted bands we have the first few letters of the alphabet. This suggests the rest of the grid should be filled in as follows
>  [image]